# Wildcard delegation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want an event to be able to be triggered by any element with the appropriate context. Right now I'm doing this:

```
$(document.body).on('mycustomevent', '*', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.log('mycustomevent')
  console.log(this)
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this? Is there a better way?

Another related question is how would I trigger this event for an element not attached to the document? ie:

```
$('<div></div>').trigger('mycustomevent')
```

Comment: You may want to avoid the `html` and `body` elements by using `body *`, though it depends on your situation.

Comment: There's not much point in the `e.stopPropagation()` call because you're already handling the event at the body level - that is, it will have already propagated up from the original target element by the time your handler is called.

Comment: without stopping propagation, the event will be triggered on every single element up the DOM tree.

Comment: But as I stated, you're handling the event at the top of the tree, because your handler is attached to the body. Your handler won't be called until _after_ the event has already propagated up through the tree.

Comment: so it won't trigger more than once?

Answer (score 0):

For part one I'd use `$(document).on` instead.

For part two just attach an event handler to the element itself.

```
$('<div></div>').on('mycustomevent', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    console.log('mycustomevent')
    console.log(this)
}).trigger('mycustomevent')
```

Comment: 1) Reasons? 2) I'm trying to avoid that since I'm trying to make my code modular (ie two modules only communicate via events)

Comment: Well its more to type, the document contains all the elements(i.e.  head, title, etc) and it looks weird.